# Zooming in Google maps api broken in mobile safari (iOS) if page is scrolled

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, mobile-safari

When using google maps API V3 in iOS' mobile safari pinch zooming is broken if the page is not scrolled to the very top.

I've tested this on an iPad 2 with iOS 5.1.1 and latest stable API V 3.9.

Page scaling is already disabled using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />`

Has anybody a solution to this?

Using an iFrame is *not* a solution. It would break the whole application, which heavily interacts with the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in google maps API 3.9. and google will fix this in 3.10, as the changelog reveals:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog

Unfortunately V3.10 is still "experimental".

Edit: It's now fixed in 3.9, too.